# Combining an ad hoc network to a wired one

Tags: omnet++

I have a few servers connected to a router and a mobile ad hoc host. What is the best way to connect the mobile host to the wired network? I want the mobile host to be able to communicate with the servers.

Comment: You can ask this question at our member Stack exchange site [superuser](http://superuser.com/questions)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the same both for OMNeT++ simulations and for real life: If you want a mobile computer to be able to communicate with a server on the Internet (or on a LAN), it's easiest to set up and configure a [wireless Access Point (AP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_access_point).

If you use OMNeT++'s INET Framework for simulation, you will find that all models needed to set up such a system are already there. Configuring IP addresses and routing can be taken care of by adding what the INET Framework calls "[Network Configurators](https://omnetpp.org/doc/inet/api-current/neddoc/index.html?p=inet.networklayer.autorouting.ipv4.FlatNetworkConfigurator.html)".